# Electrical power of 3 ph BLDC motor

Tags: motor, power-electronics

Looking for a formula to calculate electrical power of a 3 phase BLDC motor (driven of DC bus) which is sinewave commutated, specifically do I need a square root of 3 multiplier in P = I*V line-to-line formula.